# How to resolve component rendering an empty container initially and multiple instances of the component for each entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have

```
 {chatHistory.map((entry, index) => (
    <ChatHistoryDisplay
      key={index}
      user={entry.userText}
      model={entry.responseText}
    />   ))}
```

ChatHistoryDisplay component rendering an empty container initially and multiple instances of the component for each chat entry.I just want only to update the list as each entry , not call the whole component plus not need the initial empty list .

```
const ChatBar = ({ setActiveComponent }) => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("This is the current input: " + userText);
    setUserText("");
    try {
      const chat = model.startChat({
        history: [],
        generationConfig: {
          maxOutputTokens: 100,
        },
      });

      const result = await chat.sendMessage(userText);
      const response = await result.response;
      const text = await response.text();
      setChatHistory((prevHistory) => [
        ...prevHistory,
        { userText, responseText: text },
      ]);
      console.log(text);
      setActiveComponent("ChatHistoryDisplay");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false); // Reset loading state
      setUserText(""); // Clear input field
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.chatbar}>
        <form className={styles.chatbarcontainer} onSubmit={fetchData}>
          <div>
            <IoMicOutline className={styles.micicon} />
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="You can ask me anything! I am here to help."
            className={styles.chatbarinput}
            value={userText}
            onChange={(e) => setUserText(e.target.value)}
            disabled={loading}
          />
          <div className={styles.file}>
            <IoIosAttach className={styles.fileicon} />
          </div>
          <button className={styles.send} type="submit" disabled={loading}>
            <FiSend className={styles.sendicon} />
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      {chatHistory.map((entry, index) => (
        <ChatHistoryDisplay
          key={index}
          user={entry.userText}
          model={entry.responseText}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is chathistory display, where I set mu UI for display of list.

```
const ChatHistoryDisplay = ({ user, model }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.displaymain__conatiner}>
        <div className={styles.display__container}>
          <div className={styles.user__propic}>
            <img src={pro__pic} className={styles.profile__pic} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.user__top}>
            <div className={styles.user__left}>
              <div className={styles.user__username}>Ryan Lee</div>
              <div className={styles.user__status}>just now</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <PiCopyThin className={styles.user__copybtn} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.demo}></div>
          <div className={styles.user__text}>{user}</div>
        </div>
        {/* For Artificium */}

        <div className={styles.display__container}>
          <div className={styles.model__propic}>
            <img src={artificium} className={styles.model__pic} />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.model__top}>
            <div className={styles.model__left}>
              <div className={styles.model__username}>Artificium</div>
              <div className={styles.model__status}>just now</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <PiCopyThin className={styles.model__copybtn} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.demo}></div>
          <div className={styles.model__text}>{model}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```